# Jpa migration issue enable cascade persist globally

Tags: java, jpa, migration

Migrated jpa 1.x to jpa 2.x

User Entity

```
Entity
public class User {
@OneToMany(fetch= fetch type.Eager, 
cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
Private List<Address> userAddresses = 
 new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity 
public class Addresses {
@ManyToOne(fetch=fetch type.EAGER) 
@JoinColumn(name = "address_type_id")
private AddressType addressType;
}
```

When I tried to save an address,

Getting below error

However, this field does not allow cascade persist. You cannot flush unmanaged objects or graphs that have persistent associations to unmanaged objects.
Suggested actions:
a) Set the cascade attribute for this field to CascadeType.PERSIST or CascadeType.ALL (JPA annotations) or "persist" or "all" (JPA orm.xml),
b) enable cascade-persist globally,
c) manually persist the related field value prior to flushing.
d) if the reference belongs to another context, allow reference to it by setting StoreContext.setAllowReferenceToSiblingContext().

For the addresstype getting error.

This error will gone when I add cascadetype.persist

```
 Entity 
 public class Addresses { 
 @ManyToOne(fetch=fetchtype.EAGER,
 cascade= cascadetype.PERSIST)
 @JoinColumn(name   ="address_type_id")
  private AddressType addressType;
}
```

But I don't want to save to addresstype. So any other solution to fix this issue?

Comment: What value do you have/want in the address_type_id foreign key column for this use case? You can map it as a basic and populate it yourself if you need, avoiding a ManyToOne reference mapping

Comment: Address type is a master table. And I'd of addresstype is used as composite key in adress table. Addresstype I'd and address number is used as composite key in adress table. To set foreign key , this manytoone is given. The I'd of addresstype has foreign key relation with I'd of address. The I'd of address type is saved in the I'd of address. So this manytoone given to set the foreign key relation. But getting an error to persist. Address type is master table, can't persist to that table.

Comment: You haven't shown the full Address entity, and how you've mapped this address_type_id foreign key then if you are using it as a composite pk there - what you described won't work with the mapping as it is. You must have the address_type_id value as an ID. Either as a basic with the ManyToOne reference marked as read only (insertable/writable=false) or with this mapping being annotated as the ID. The first option would allow you to null out the addressType  reference outright and just set the basic mapping for the address_type_id will the value, avoiding your issue.

Answer (score 0):

From https://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.4.2/apache-openjpa/docs/jpa_2.2.html

Cascade persist behavior
In previous releases, OpenJPA would check the database for the existence of the related Entity before persisting the relationship to that Entity. This resulted in an extra Select being sent to the database. In 2.2.0, code was added so that when cascading a persist to a related Entity without persistence state, the persist (insert) will happen without first checking the database. This may result in an EntityExistsException if the related Entity already exists in the database. To revert this behavior to the previous release, set the value of the openjpa.Compatibility property CheckDatabaseForCascadePersistToDetachedEntity to true.

After set CheckDatabaseForCascadePersistToDetachedEntity true, the error gone.